# How to implement this JavaScript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, time

This is a  JavaScript  showing time hour, minute and seconds now seconds are ticking minutes change it's not static  i have problem.How  to implement it in HTML page ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function startTime() {
      var today = new Date();
      var h = today.getHours();
      var m = today.getMinutes();
      var s = today.getSeconds();
      m = checkTime(m);
      s = checkTime(s);
      document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
      t = setTimeout('startTime()', 500);
  }

  function checkTime(i) {
      if (i < 10) {
          i = "0" + i;
      }
      return i;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `<script>` is an HTML element so it is not very clear what you are tryng to achieve ..

Comment: Just call `startTime()` somewhere in your script... like just before `</script>` and have a element with id `txt` in your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your body tag to

```
<body  onload="startTime()">
<span id="txt">10:26:07</span>
```

Than add bellow code where you want clock to appear

Answer (score 0):

Just do it:

```
<span id="txt"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function startTime() {
      var today = new Date();
      var h = today.getHours();
      var m = today.getMinutes();
      var s = today.getSeconds();
      m = checkTime(m);
      s = checkTime(s);
      document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
      t = setTimeout('startTime()', 500);
  }

  function checkTime(i) {
      if (i < 10) {
          i = "0" + i;
      }
      return i;
  }

  startTime();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be so many version of HTML Markup for your Javascript function:

One of them could be like:

```
<div id="txt">
</div>
<button type="button" name="click" onclick="startTime()">Click Me!</button>
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/haLdcvr5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

- You need an element on your page with ID `txt` (see your script.)
- You need to start/call your function execution `startTime();`
- In order to allow the JS DOM parser to find your `#txt` place your `<script>` before the closing `</body>` tag.

```html
<div id="txt"></div>

<script>
  const startTime = (elTarget) => {
    const now = new Date();
    const h = now.getHours();
    let m = now.getMinutes();
    let s = now.getSeconds();
    m = `${m}`.padStart(2, "0");
    s = `${s}`.padStart(2, "0");
    elTarget.textContent = `${h}:${m}:${s}`;
    setTimeout(startTime.bind(null, elTarget), 1000);
  };

  startTime(document.querySelector("#txt"));
</script>

<!-- closing </body> tag here -->
```